# IntelliJ 2023.1 - Can't change log level in run / console (Using Gradle 7.3 / Grails 5.1.3 / Open JDK 11)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, logging, grails

I am not able to change my console log output from info to lifecycle or other parameters so that I get a clearer output in the console.

Currently I get a 100 lines long output on every run (mostly INFO), that e.g. all plug-ins have been loaded successfully.

After some research this should be possible either via the project configurations (Log-Tab) or via gradle.properties using the command:

org.gradle.logging.level=lifecycle

I don't have a logs tab in my Configurations, nor does changing org.gradle.logging.level give a clearer result.

What could be the reason for this?